# What is the equvalent interpolation from matlab in python?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, interpolation

I want to rewrite a code from matlab to python. In matlab I have the following:

```
interp1(TMP.time_hor, TMP.lane_hor, TMP.travel_time, 'next') % matlab
```

Which interpolation is meant by 'next'? Usually by default is linear. Is there a numpy equivalent? For example:

```
numpy.interp(x, xp, fp, left=None, right=None, period=None) # python
```

which is 'linear' interpolated...

Comment: Look into scipy, its interpolation function should support the 'next' method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which interpolation is meant by `'next'`? Usually by default is linear. Is there a numpy equivalent?

The interpolation method `'next'` interpolates to the next data point in the data set (see: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html).

Looking at NumPy's documentation (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html), it appears as though they use linear interpolation, so if you want the same output, you just need to specify this in your MATLAB command, like this:

```
interp1(TMP.time_hor, TMP.lane_hor, TMP.travel_time, 'linear')
```

That being said, `'linear'` is the default interpolation method for `interp1`, so you can also simply leave that argument out and use the command:

```
interp1(TMP.time_hor, TMP.lane_hor, TMP.travel_time)
```

I hope this helps!

Edit: I just realized what you were asking was backwards you want to interpolate using the 'next' method in Python instead. Here's how I'd do it:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp

# Generate data
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
y = np.exp(x)

# Create interpolation function 
f = sp.interpolate.interp1d(x, y, 'next')

# Create resampled range
x_resampled = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 100)

# Here's your interpolated data
y_interpolated = f(x_resampled)
```

Comment: The other way around. I want to have 'next' in the python implementation.

Comment: Oh my mistake, I should have read your question more carefully! Please see my edit to my previous answer above :)